# Object is possibly null - even after null check

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript 2.8

My code is this:

```
class Wizard extends React.Componenet {

    private divElement: null | HTMLDivElement = null;

    componentDidUpdate(_: IWizardProps, prevState: IWizardState) {
        if (this.divElement) {
            this.getOverflowParent(this.divElement).scrollTop = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

I wrap it with an `if` to ensure it is not `null`, however compiler keeps failing saying it is possibly `null`. May you please advise?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should try checking if `this.getOverflowParent(this.divElement)` is null before using it's `scrollTop` property.

Comment: Oh thank you!!! That fixed it!

Comment: @sme Do you mind writing this as a (possibly more verbose) answer so this question could be marked as solved?

Comment: @Cerberus Alright, I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check if `this.getOverflowParent(this.divElement)` is null before using its `scrollTop` property. For example,

```
if (this.divElement) {
    var overflowParent = this.getOverflowParent(this.divElement);
    if (overflowParent)
        overflowParent.scrollTop = 0;
}
```